# Table structures for files and images

Tags: mysql, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm designing a database for a new CMS and having some trouble structuring tables for files and images.

Current design is to have tables with file info:

- `files`: `name`, `filename`, `extension`, `lang`, `size`
- `images`: `name`, `filename`, `exstension`, `alt`

Above them are tables for specific types named: `product_files`, `article_files`.
They have fields like (for `product` and `images`): `id`, `image_id`, `product_id`, `position`.

These tables are there because it can happen that different products have same images.
The thing is, I'm repeating those middle tables for every use case (2 for products, 2 for articles, etc.).

I was thinking of combining them in one table like:

- `items_images` with columns: `table`, `table_id`, `image_id`, `position`

Is that a good way to go? Or should I leave it as is? To my knowledge I can't set foreign keys on a table like that connecting it to tables of products or articles.

Edit:

It seems I wasn't very clear about the problem. I don't know how to best display it here so I'll explain the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwUjM.png): [image: tables structure] Just ignore the lines.

Top row are tables with actual file info. Documents, images and videos respectively.
Middle row are six tables grouped into three and each group connected to their table (products and articles). What I would like to do is make only three out of those six but still keep them connected to both products and articles at the same time. Maybe the solution is some 4th table but I don't know.

Comment: Sounds like you're duplicating tables a bit there, it doesn't sound very well normalised. What do you mean by "I can't set foreign keys on a table like that"?

Comment: I know I'm duplicating but I'm also currently stuck. I'd like to normalize them but also be able to connect tables with foreign keys. Here is a picture to current model. I cut out unimportant parts so maybe someting's missing. http://i.imgur.com/6lD73.jpg

Comment: Can you edit your question with some tables that show the FK you cannot create? I'm not sure what restrictions you're thinking of.

Comment: @Cylindric You can see in the image above that I have 6 tables. 3 pairs of 2 that are basically the same, just connecting to different tables(products and articles). And there will probably be 3rd type soon so I'd like to combine this somehow but still keep relational integrity.

Comment: Sorry, it looked like a huge spread out mix of tables with no layout that I could follow. Generally, if you can't articulate your problem in a single question here, it's not going to be easy for *us* to do so from a spaghetti-diagram. A bit of formatting in the question, maybe some examples, go a long way to helping us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table structure like :

id, image_id, pointer_id, position, type

where type will tell if it's a product, article etc.